# Ошибка при старте отладчика в Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Решил научится писать программы, скачал учебники, зашел в VSE написал строки, которые были написаны в учебнике. Потом нажал "Начать отладку", а мне пишет вот такое

> Не удается запустить программу ... 
> Не удается найти указанный файл

А Вот сам код

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А при сборке (компиляции) какие сообщения выдаются?

Comment: В самом деле, какие сообщения? Может быть об ошибке cl.exe или link.exe. Какое у Вас? Ведь должно же указывать, какой файл не может найти...

Answer (score 3):

Ваш проект содержит ошибки: либо не компилируется, либо не линкуется. Поэтому в папке, где должен лежать исполняемый файл, ничего нет и отладчик не запускается.

Создайте готовый проект консольного приложения по шаблону Visual Studio и экспериментируйте на нем, тогда все будет ок.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
#include <iostream>
```

попробуй

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

Comment: Неправильный совет. Дело в том, что в C++ некоторые заголовки идут уже без расширения *.h. Сделано скорее всего, чтобы различать CPPшные и оригинальные Сишные заголовочные файлы. Можно самому убедиться, что iostream без расширения, порыскав по include-каталогам студии.

Comment: Почти. На самом деле файл без расширения iostream -- это тот же iostream.h, но только первый используется в новых версиях Студии. В старых же версиях можно использовать с расширением *.h, особенно если проект не С++, а С. Как пример: пишем cstdio, но можно stdio.h, или cstdlib вместо stdlib.h. Возможно, в новых версиях Майкрософт уже переходит на файлы без расширения, вместо расширений *.h.

Comment: Вы, видимо, отстали от жизни. Во-первых, gcc ест именно вариант iostream. Во-вторых, в студии начиная где-то с 2005-й версии уже все работает как iostream. А тем более в студии 2010.<p>
<i>но можно stdio.h</i><p>
Так дык... В С это и будет Сишный заголовок. А cstdio по идее не должен даваться подключаться, т.к. может лежать в каталоге инклюдов С++.